# document.ready doesn't when you have a tab a page src

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

The homepage is home.jsp and it contains 4 tabs. I am displaying a image slider in tab 2 using JSP include src. The problem is the slide doesnt work as expected when the tab 2 is clicked. The image slider JSP uses document.ready. This JSP works when it is viewed stand alone or when the tab order is specified as 1 instead of 2 in the homepage. I have tried many options like document.window,document.ready. Below is the code.

```
 $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        //Set Default State of each portfolio piece
        $(".paging").show();
        $(".paging a:first").addClass("active");

    //Get size of images, how many there are, then determin the size of the image reel.
    var imageWidth = $(".window_spot").width();
    var imageSum = $(".image_reel img").size();
    var imageReelWidth = imageWidth * imageSum;


    //Adjust the image reel to its new size
    $(".image_reel").css({'width' : imageReelWidth});

    //Paging + Slider Function
    rotate = function(){    
        var triggerID = $active.attr("rel") - 1; //Get number of times to slide
        var image_reelPosition = triggerID * imageWidth; //Determines the distance the image reel needs to slide

        $(".paging a").removeClass('active'); //Remove all active class
        $active.addClass('active'); //Add active class (the $active is declared in the rotateSwitch function)

        //Slider Animation
        $(".image_reel").animate({ 
            left: -image_reelPosition
        }, 500 );

    }; 

    //Rotation + Timing Event
    rotateSwitch = function(){      
        play = setInterval(function(){ //Set timer - this will repeat itself every 3 seconds
            $active = $('.paging a.active').next();
            if ( $active.length === 0) { //If paging reaches the end...
                $active = $('.paging a:first'); //go back to first
            }
            rotate(); //Trigger the paging and slider function
        }, 7000); //Timer speed in milliseconds (3 seconds)
    };

    rotateSwitch(); //Run function on launch

    //On Hover
    $(".image_reel a").hover(function() {
        clearInterval(play); //Stop the rotation
    }, function() {
        rotateSwitch(); //Resume rotation
    }); 

    //On Click
    $(".paging a").click(function() {   
        $active = $(this); //Activate the clicked paging
        //Reset Timer
        clearInterval(play); //Stop the rotation
        rotate(); //Trigger rotation immediately
        rotateSwitch(); // Resume rotation
        return false; //Prevent browser jump to link anchor
    }); 

});
```

Comment: Are your tabs new pages (load a whole new URL from scratch) or just a different view of the same content?  Only loading a new URL causes a new `document.ready()` to fire.

Comment: Each tabs loads a JSP page dynamically, and the whole tab setup is in one single JSP(homeinc.jsp). Any other work around? Thanks for your response

Answer (score 1):

Since you've now explained that you're loading the tabbed content dynamically (which I assume means via ajax), there will be no new `document.ready()` for that dynamically loaded content.  Instead, you need to use the success handler for the ajax call that loads the content and trigger the code you want to run when the new content is loaded.  You will need to trigger that code yourself - there is no event to do it automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, can you give me an exaxmple or sample code to do that. I can that code in the tab click function. Thanks

Comment: Do I need to use Load function for tabs? Can you give me a sample I am new to jquery. Something like when I click a tab, the page has been loaded with the image slider. Is it possible?

Comment: Show us the code that loads the tab content and we can offer better ideas.

Comment: Below is the code which loads the files for each tabs using include SRC. <dsp:oparam name="false">
  <dsp:setvalue param="subtabNames" paramvalue="element.subtabNames"/>
  <c:set var="_jspPage"><dsp:valueof param="element.jspPageUrl"/></c:set>
  <dsp:include src="${_jspPage}" />/*this is place where tabs are loaded with JSP's*/       
  </dsp:oparam>                                                                                         The image slider is a JSP where it has the above Javascript, and its own CSS. One of the things I found out when the tab is at position 1 (selected) it works

Comment: I tried so many types of image sliders, none works when it is embedded inside a tab. This should be global bug or may there are better ideas.